# PL\SQL statement ignored error

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am beginner to PL\SQL and while practicing a small code, I am getting errors as below

```
Error(7,1): PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Error(7,13): PLS-00302: component 'PUT_LINES' must be declared
Error(10,1): PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Error(10,50): PLS-00201: identifier 'LEGTH' must be declared
```

And this is the code I am using for practice

```
create or replace procedure show_variable_length as 
    my_char char(50) := 'Hello';
    my_varchar  varchar(25) := 'World';
    my_varchar2 varchar2(25) := 'World';
    my_null_test varchar2(25);

begin 
dbms_output.put_lines (my_char || ' ' || my_varchar);
dbms_output.put_line (my_char || ' ' || my_varchar2);
dbms_output.put_line('Length of my_char = ' || length(my_char));
dbms_output.put_line('Lenght of my_varchar= ' || legth(my_varchar));
dbms_output.put_line('Length of my_varchar2 = ' || length(my_varchar2));
my_char := ' ';
my_varchar := ' ';
my_varchar2 := ' ';
dbms_output.put_line ('Length of my char = ' || length(my_char));
end;
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is spelling mistake in keyword length(legth without n) and put_line(put_lines with additional s at end)

Line with spelling mistake in keyword length

```
dbms_output.put_line('Lenght of my_varchar= ' || legth(my_varchar));
```

Line with spelling mistake in put_line

```
dbms_output.put_lines(my_char || ' ' || my_varchar);
```

Rectified code

```
create or replace procedure show_variable_length as 
    my_char char(50) := 'Hello';
    my_varchar  varchar(25) := 'World';
    my_varchar2 varchar2(25) := 'World';
    my_null_test varchar2(25);

begin 
dbms_output.put_line(my_char || ' ' || my_varchar);
dbms_output.put_line(my_char || ' ' || my_varchar2);
dbms_output.put_line('Length of my_char = ' || length(my_char));
dbms_output.put_line('Lenght of my_varchar= ' || length(my_varchar));
dbms_output.put_line('Length of my_varchar2 = ' || length(my_varchar2));
my_char := ' ';
my_varchar := ' ';
my_varchar2 := ' ';
dbms_output.put_line('Length of my char = ' || length(my_char));
end;
```